# Closing form Popup window on submit

Tags: jquery, html

I have a popup form which is called using:

```
$(function() {
    $('#add-company').click(function() {
        $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
    })
});
```

I then submit the form via Ajax using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sbmt").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var one = document.getElementById("one").value;
        var two = document.getElementById("two").value;

        var DataForm = 'one1=' + one + '&two1=' + two;
        if (one == '' || two == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        } 
        else {
        // AJAX code to submit form.
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/ajax.php',
                data: DataForm,
                dataType:"json", 
                success:function() {
                    $('#company-form').each(function(){
                        this.reset();   //Here form fields will be cleared.
                    });
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('#contactForm3').fadeToggle();
                }
            });
            return false;  
        }
    });
});
```

I am looking to have the form close when the data has been updated, as you can see, I have added:

```
complete: function(){
    $('#contactForm3').fadeToggle();
}
```

but no joy.

Which works fine for most fields but there are a couple of dropdown `<select>` fields which this does not clear so If I open the form again, the  fields remain populated.

Form code incase needed

```
<div id="contactForm3">
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form  action="" method="POST" name="company-form" id="company-form">
        <span>
            <label>One</label>
            <input id="one" name="one" placeholder="one" type="text" required />
        </span>
        <span>
            <select id="two" name="two" class="limitedNumbChosen" multiple="false">
                <option value="Y">Yes</option>
                <option value="N">No</option>
            </select>
        <input id="sbmit" class="formBtn" type="submit" />
        <input class="formBtn" type="reset" />
       </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

UPDATE

If I use

```
success: function() {
    alert('Message sent');
},
complete: function(){
    $('#dataForm3').each(function(){
        this.reset();   //Here form fields will be cleared.
    });
}
```

This clears the form which I suppose is a start...

I have tried using `this.fadetoggle();` but is not an accepted function... I use the recent version of jQuery and it works to open the form but not close it?

Comment: Can you please provide a working sample(jsfiddle/codepen)?

Comment: @dganenco https://jsfiddle.net/9m8oca37/ Fiddle with the same code as I am using... the confusing thing though... when I press submit, the window closes... Hard to show the other issue, as in order to get the form back, need to re-run the module so the form is automatically blanked out

Comment: Im thinking that the ajax command in the JS might be causing the form to close so giving a false impression that the code is working to close the form on submit in the fiddle

Comment: give success function like `success:function() {
    $('#company-form').reset();
},` and add an empty  option for the select as `<option></option>`

Comment: @NijinKoderi adding a blank `<option></option>` doesnt do anything as the form doesnt reset to the top option, it holds the option that was chosen. so as above, if i selected `No`, then the next time the form was opened (providing the page was not refreshed), `No` would be preselected in that field

Comment: @NijinKoderi solved that problem swapping `<select>` with `<input><datalist>` main issue now is closing the form on submit

Comment: Is it a modal popup?

Comment: @NijinKoderi yes, it is basically a div that appears over the top of the current page

Comment: @NijinKoderi sorry, Ive been looking and Ill change my previous answer, the form is similar to modal but is not a modal form. I would change to run on modal but I have various different forms and would take a lot of work updating them all

Comment: Not sure if it is only in the sample, but isn't the problem in the fact that you are opening 'contactForm3', but closing 'contactForm'?

Comment: @zelitomas sorry, that's just the sample, I must have missed the '3' when typing it here.  Good spot lol